# Mysql repetitive result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query using  INNER JOIN. below the code:

```
 <?php 
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT pub.nomett, cont
FROM pub
INNER JOIN prop
   ON prop.nomett = pub.nomett " );

 var_dump($result);
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {         
       
        
echo "<div class='horizontal_dotted_line'";
        echo "<td>".$res['nomett']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$res['cont']."</td>";

   
             echo "</div>";
              

   }
    ?>
```

```
   In DB there are 2 tables: PUB/ PROP
    columns:
         PUB: idpub/cont/nomett
         PROP: idprop/nomett
```

The problem is that in Prop table there are many {idprop} using the same {nomett}.

When i execute the query, it displays {cont} repeated as many {nomett} are repeated in the table.
How to avoid that?

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove duplicates.

Comment: Why do you join to the table as you don't seem to use anything from it?

Comment: @NigelRen because all idprop are linked to nomett which is present in table pub.

Comment: @Barmar . Excellent. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use `prop` for filtering, since you are not displaying any column from that table in the resultset.

If so, you can use `exists` to avoid "multiplying" the `pub` rows when there are several matches in `prop`:

```
select nomett, cont
from pub pu
where exists (select 1 from prop pr where pr.nomett = pu.nomett)
```

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT nomett, cont
FROM pub pu  WHERE exists (select 1 from prop pr where pr.nomett = pu.nomett");            the result didnt throw any error but nothing is diplayed. VARDUMP:  object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Please How to flag question as answered?